# Combining Functions Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question:

If $f(x)=x^2-x+2$ and $g(x)=x-2$, find $h(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(h(x))$

I am not sure if I am on the right track here so far, I came to this mostly through guess and check, perhaps there is a better way?

Edit: got it.

$$f(x)=g(h(x))\\x^2-x+2=g(h(x))\\x^2-x+2=h(x)-2\\h(x)=x^2-x+4$$

Comment: $g(h(x)) = h(x)-2$ not $x-2$

Comment: Oh wow, no wonder I was getting confused lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$g(h(x))=h(x)-2$$

Comment: Ah, was confusing myself.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Happy one to you too. I inly hope God accept our deeds during this holy month. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there!! I would just say, let $h(x)=y$.

$$f(x)=g(h(x))\\x^2-x+2=g(h(x))=g(y)\\x^2-x+2=y-2\\x^2-x+2=y-2\\y=x^2-x+4$$